# Can't compile example with __stdcall in Boost.Python

Tags: c++, boost-python, msvc12

I'm trying to wrap a function in Python using `Boost.Python` and I'm facing problems when I use `__stdcall` . Here's an example:

```
#define BOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB
#define BOOST_PYTHON_ENABLE_STDCALL
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/python/signature.hpp>

void __stdcall f(void) 
{
    return;
}

using namespace boost::python;

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(MyPyDLL)
{
    def("func", f);
}
```

When I try to compile I get more than 100 similar errors, but the first 2 are:

> error C2780:
>   'boost::mpl::vector10::type&,T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7>
>   boost::python::detail::get_signature(RT (__thiscall ClassT::*
>   )(T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7) const,Target *)': expects 2 arguments - 1
>   provided
>   C:\boost\boost_1_62_0_python\boost\python\make_function.hpp   104
>
> error C2780:
>   'boost::mpl::vector10::type&,T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7>
>   boost::python::detail::get_signature(RT (__thiscall ClassT::*
>   )(T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7) volatile const,Target *)': expects 2
>   arguments - 1 provided
>   C:\boost\boost_1_62_0_python\boost\python\make_function.hpp   104

As you can see, I used the define `BOOST_PYTHON_ENABLE_STDCALL` , which is mentioned in [this page:](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/python/doc/v2/configuration.html)

but the problem stays the same with or without defining it.

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

You will get that error if you define BOOST_PYTHON_ENABLE_STDCALL after you import the boost header files.